# Iniciante - Netbeans IDE 18 - Java com Gradle - Dúvidas!

Tags: java, apache, netbeans, gradle, ant

Olá, tudo bem?
Estou dando os primeiros passos com java, uso o Netbeans no linux (kali) e estou com dúvidas.

Estava usando a versão IDE 12, migrei para o IDE 18 e notei algumas diferenças.

1 - Por que quando eu crio um projeto usando gradle na IDE 18, o nome da classe vem com App e não como Main?

2 - Posso alterar para Main ao invés de App?

3 - Por que ele criou o grandleproject6 e o gradleproject6.app e qual a diferença entre os dois?

4 - Posso usar o Java com Ant para fazer o mesmo que eu faço com gradle?

Obrigado!

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtkjK.png)

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqgpm.png)

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2voTM.png)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Respondendo as perguntas:

1. Na criação de projeto usando o assistente do netbeans. É criado
   usando uma classe exemplo e geralmente é a classe App.java que
   possui um metodo main().
2. Pode alterar a classe App para qualquer outro nome que desejar.
   Ou criar outra com outro nome e adicionar o metodo main(). Lembrando
   se for criar outra classe para ser a classe principal. tem que
   alterar no arquivo build.gradle Exemplo se for alterar o nome da
   classe App para Main.

faça de:

```
 application {
        // Define the main class for the application.
        mainClass = 'gradleproject6.App'
    }
```

para:

```
 application {
            // Define the main class for the application.
            mainClass = 'gradleproject6.Main'
     }
```

3. Acho que é um padrão de separação de arquivos do netbeans
4. Não.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.